# Nested IF formula with 4 possible outputs

Tags: excel, formula

```
Question 1  Response 1  Question 2  Response 2  Question 3
XXXX        If Yes      YYY         If Yes      AAA 
                                    If No       BBB         
            If No       ZZZ         If Yes      CCC
                                    If No       DDD
```

This is my formula for Question 2.

```
=+IF($J7="Planned - Shift / Vacation Coverage", IF(Q7="No", "Is afternoon/night shift fully staffed (already 4)?","Can scheduled work be assigned to an Eng/Helper on next day/shift? (non critical work)")
```

Each of my questions 2 will have a yes and no response.

What is the best formula for question 3 if it will depend on Response 1 and Response 2?????
Please help!!!!

---

Hello again,

I am still working on my decision form and ran into another problem.  This is my formula:

=+IF($J7="Planned - Shift / Vacation Coverage",IF(O7="No","Is Helper out during day shift?","Is an Eng out during day shift?"),
IF($J7="Planned - Off-shift PMs",IF(O7="No","Schedules OT - STOP","LE schedules work within shift - STOP"),
IF($J7="Planned - Training",IF(O7="No","Schedules training during shift - STOP","Schedules OT - STOP"),
IF($J7="Unplanned - Sick call in",IF(O7="No","Is Helper out during day shift?","Is an Eng out during day shift?"),
IF($J7="Unplanned - Emergency response/repair", IF(N7="Can this be handled by scheduled resources within shift?", IF(O7="No","Is the request a code 2?","Work is executed within shift - STOP"), IF(N7="Is the request a code 3?", IF(O7="No", "Schedules OT - STOP","Can this be handled by scheduled resources within shift?"),
IF($J7="Unplanned - Weather",IF(N7="Can resources be allocated from the shift in the first instance?",IF(O7="No","Schedules OT - STOP","CE assigns work to LE - STOP"), IF(N7="Can CE or ACE become the additional HC?",IF(O7="No","Schedules OT - STOP","CE or ACE covers shift - STOP")))))))))))

I am getting the expected outcome for each of the OT types with the exception of the last one – “Unplanned – Weather”.  It is a binary IF formula, similar to the one above “Unplanned – Emergency response/repair”, but for some reason, this one is working but the former one is not….
I need your help one more time!!!!!  Thank you so much!

Comment: nice follow up question from yesterday!  The binary tree is a very nice touch!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same result by looking up the previous result and returning a next step.

If I take your setup and put it in the following columns with the headings in row 1

```
A           B           C           D           E          F
Question 1  Response 1  Question 2  Response 2  Question 3 Response 3
XXXX        YES         yyy         YES         aaa        ?
```

and then place a lookup table like this:

```
I                   J
Previous Decision   Next
xxxxYES             yyy
xxxxYESyyyYES       aaa
xxxxYESyyyYESaaaYES         
xxxxNO              zzz
xxxxNOzzzYES        ccc
```

We can merge the questions and answers in a lookup formula and get the result:

so if you replace C2 with `=VLOOKUP(A2&B2,I:J,2,FALSE)` it will return yyy
and if you replace E2 with `=VLOOKUP(A2&B2&C2&D2,I:J,2,FALSE)` will return aaa

If you prefer using an INDEX/MATCH combo:

so if you replace C2 with `=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(A3&B3,I:I,0))` it will return yyy
and if you replace E2 with `=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(A3&B3&C3&D3,I:I,0))` will return aaa

This way you can just simply write all the combinations you want into the lookup table?

To avoid seeing #N/A I would use some error trapping to wrap those formulas so for the first vlookup I gave above which is going in C2 you could write: `=IF(B6="","",VLOOKUP(A6&B6,I:J,2,FALSE))` This will check if the answer is blank and if it is simply return a blank. Doing it this way means if the question is answered but there is no match you will get an #N/A from the lookup which will help you highlight any combinations you may have missed in the lookup table

Edit: Using the lookup table means you are not limited to YES and NO answers, as long as you write out the combinations you can add more options.